# Display 2nd page of tiff with coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, tiff

I am trying to display a tif as a pdf document using coldfusion with the following code:

```
<cfdocument format="pdf" overwrite="1" margintop="1">
    <img src="test3.tif" />
</cfdocument>
```

Now this works, but it will only show the first page of the tiff.  Is there anyway to specifically load a 2nd or 3rd page?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use imageUtils (http://imageutils.riaforge.org/) from RIAForge to extra TIFF pages. You would need to edit your HTML inside cfdocument obviously to put each page you want to use.

Comment: That seems to do it!  not the fastest splitter in the world, but i think it will fit my needs.  Thanks!